# ssh2 scp via php from win do unix does not work

Tags: php, linux, window, scp

I'm currently stuck with a weird issue:
When copying a file **from a windows remote machine to local unix one**, it's failing due to not found file on remote.

**Error:**

```
Warning: ssh2_scp_recv(): Unable to receive remote file
```

**php code**

```
ssh2_scp_recv($connection, "textexample", "nexText.txt");
```

**usual scp is working:**

```
scp user@host:textexample textexample
```

As I was trying to send (programatically) via ssh2_scp_send it was working but file on remote host was named 'textexample' (with those quotes).
So assumption is that there somewher windows is screwing it up ;)

On Windows side after ssh in the user has cmd session. But afaik this should not do anything here (and usual SCP is working anyways).

Any ad hoc ideas?

Best,
Bent

Comment: I can’t help you with your exact problem, but I dev on Windows all day and very recently fought SSH and SCP problems myself. My solution was to just switch it https://phpseclib.com/ which is native PHP and worked cross platform, even with SSH keys

Comment: Noice, Mate!
Works on first try.

Seems to be the better lib without further dependencies. Thx very much for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make sure nobody else is stumbling upon that nasty-ness here :)

I solved it with the suggested lib from [@Chris Haas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/231316/chris-haas) in comment above:

> [phpseclib.com](https://phpseclib.com)

```php
    $sftp = new SFTP($remoteHost, $port);
    if ($sftp->login($username, $password)) {
        echo "Password authentication successful\n";

        // Trying to download one file
        if ($sftp->get('textexample', 'textexample')) {
            echo "Copied one file successfully\n";
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    echo "Password authentication not successful\n";
    return false;
```

Does the trick!